# Props are not passed when open <router-link> in a new tab

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a route:

```
{ path: "reporting/report/result", name: "reportResult", component: ResultTable, props: true }
```

And a router-link:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'reportResult', params: {reportId: 21, tableData: 'data'}}" target="_blank">{{ report.reportId }}</router-link>
```

But props are not passed to the child component. If use router-link without `target="_blank"` all works fine. Probably there is another way to open link in a new tab and pass props to it?

Answer (score 2):

The router link params options doesn't pass your object in query, if you want pass your object, you must use the query args.
According to vue router docs

```
// named route
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }})

// with query, resulting in /reportResult?reportId=21&tableData=data
router.push({ path: 'reportResult', query: {reportId: 21, tableData: 'data'}})
```

In you'r page, you access to your query with :

```
this.$route.query.reportId (or this.$route.params.reportId, I don't remember)
```

Comment: it is "this.$route.query.reportId"